# Library not loaded: @rpath/libomp.dylib Reason: image not found

Tags: python, macos, scikit-learn, anaconda

I'm getting this error from the line `from skimage.morphology import label`.
The full import error is:

```
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/Kathy/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/skimage/feature/_cascade.cpython-37m-darwin.so, 2): Library not loaded: @rpath/libomp.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/Kathy/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/skimage/feature/_cascade.cpython-37m-darwin.so
  Reason: image not found
```

I installed scikit-image through `pip install scikit_image`. Any suggestions for fixes?

Comment: I think `conda install -c conda-forge llvm-openmp` might fix this. That said, I strongly recommend installing packages with `conda install <pkg-name>` instead of `pip install <pkg-name>` whenever possible. This often leads to less problems with packages that depend on non-python code/libraries.

Comment: Does the .so have the correct @rpath?  Inspect with otool -l ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/skimage/feature/_cascade.cpython-37m-darwin.so

Comment: ah the `conda install -c conda-forge llvm-openmp` command worked! thank you @cel